# No source strings to translate on the admin links page

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, localization

There're a couple of strings that don't have any source to translate on the [moderator links page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/links):

- Lists posts (questions and answers) deleted by their authors, sorted from most recent to least recent.
- All site moderators must review and accept the terms of this moderator agreement in order to access the ♦ moderator functions. Any user can view the moderator agreement here.